# Max() in impala not resulting correct value

Tags: sql, impala

I have 3 rows with column range and i want to pull Max value using the query in impala. But the resulted output returning 8 instead of 30

```
range
-----
-15
8
30
```

Query:

```
select max(range) from table1
```

Output is resulting

> 8 instead 30.

i also tried retrieving the record in asc order interestingly it resulted in value in order like

```
-15
30
8
```

which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The value is stored as a number instead of a string.  You can cast before taking the max.  Assuming they are integers:

```
select max(cast(range as int))
from table1 ;
```

Comment: If you arent sure about data type, use - SELECT  max(cast(20 as double)) FROM table1;